# C++ Dynamic memory allocation VS Automatic memory allocation

Tags: c++, out-of-memory

Fairly strange thing that, I build a search tree and search it. In the search function, if I dynamically allocate memory and delete, memory limit will exceed(I am solving problem in an OJ). But if I just declare an ordinary variable, there is no out of memory issue. Code looks like this:(I recursively search a tree(similar to a 2DTree))

```
void Search(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, node* n, int* st, long long* tem)    {
    int nx, ny, nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2;
    nx = n->x; ny = n->y;
    nx1 = n->x1; nx2 = n->x2;
    ny1 = n->y1; ny2 = n->y2;
    node* l = n->lc;
    node* r = n->rc;
    if (x1 > nx2 || x2<nx1 || y1>ny2 || y2 < ny1) { 
        *st = 0;
        *tem = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if (x1 <= nx1 && x2 >= nx2 && y1 <= ny1 && y2 >= ny2) { 
        *st = n->childNum;
        *tem = n->tSum;
        return;
    }
    else {  
        //part with memory issue
        long long* tl = new long long;
        int* sl = new int;
        *tl = 0;  *sl = 0;
        if (l) Search(x1, x2, y1, y2, l, sl, tl);
        *st += (*sl );
        *tem += (*tl);
        delete tl, sl;
        long long* tr = new long long;
        int* sr = new int;
        if (r) Search(x1, x2, y1, y2, r, sr, tr);
        *st += (*sr);
        *tem += (*tr);
        delete tr, sr;
        if (nx >= x1 && nx <= x2 && ny >= y1 && ny <= y2) { 
            *st += 1;
            *tem += n->t;
        }

        //this goes OK
        long long tl = 0;
        int sl = 0;
        if (l) Search(x1, x2, y1, y2, l, &sl, &tl);
        *st += (sl);
        *tem += (tl);
        long long tr = 0;
        int sr = 0;
        if (r) Search(x1, x2, y1, y2, r, &sr, &tr);
        *st += (sr);
        *tem += (tr);
        if (nx >= x1 && nx <= x2 && ny >= y1 && ny <= y2) { 
            *st += 1;
            *tem += n->t;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `delete tl, sl;` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @nwp what do you mean? It does not free the allocated space?

Comment: It effectively does `delete sl;` which leaves a memory leak on `tl`. You should not manually use `new` and `delete` in C++. It is inefficient, difficult to get right and unnecessary.

Comment: @nwp `delete` has higher precedence than `,`. Doesn't that mean `delete tl, sl;` will be parsed as `(delete tl), sl;` and deallocate only `tl`?

Comment: @DannyuNDos Yes it does. That is also what the link in the answer says and the comment below highlighted.

Comment: a method with 7 parameters, 7 opportunities to give a meaningful name, and the longer name in the list is a so helpful `tem`. Sooner or later someone (maybe you) will have to read, understand and possibly modify your code. Help that poor guy

Comment: Perhaps start using variable names that are meaningful. Smart pointers perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @nwp, I realize that this is a trivial problem.

The reason that the original code didn't work is that `delete` has higher precedence than comma, so `delete a, b, c;` is the same as `(delete a), b, c`, so,

`delete a,b,c;` only deletes a.

Likewise, `cin >> a,b;` is the same as `cin >> a;`

check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/51496/)

Comment: Keep reading that link. Other way around - only deletes `a`, `cin>>a`.

Comment: Please mention the reason (operator precedence) and how it works, and get an upvote. Answers need to be full, and enlightening, even if it is your own. You can't rely on the link staying forever - leave it for reference, but write here the important parts. You can check [answer].